# Dimension of a span

Tags: linear-algebra

Use the coordinate vectors to test the linear independence of the following set of polynomials:

$$\left\{ (2−t)^3, (3−t)^2, 1+6t-5t^2+t^3 \right\}.$$

What is the dimension of the span of this set of polynomials?

I was able to prove its linear independence. Would the dimension just be $3$ (the number of pivot columns)?

Thanks

Comment: If they are linearly independent, then they are a basis for their span.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have been able to prove its independence, you are correct. This is because if vectors are linearly independent, they are a basis for what they span. The dimension is indeed $3$, as dimension is just equal to the number of vectors in the basis.